# Mac does a sort of freezing thing randomly but does not seem aware that it is frozen

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro

I am not sure why but tonight there have been two instances where my new MacBook pro updated to the latest OS has complexly frozen.

However it is an unusual kind of freeze. The mouse still moves across the screen however there is no rolling beachball. No clicking, gestures, commands, or touch-bar inputs work for a few moments. Music (from Spotify) however does keep playing. The computer doesn't even seem aware that it is frozen.

Then after awhile it will spontaneously come back to life executing every keyboard command, click, and touch I did while it was frozen.

Any clue what kinds of things could cause this and how I can prevent them?

Comment: [SMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Controller), maybe? I experienced similar freezes on an old (2007) MacBook with OS X 10.6 and an [SMC reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) seemed to help.

Comment: Stuck process or massive memory swap? - pictures of Activity Monitor, CPU & Memory pages might help [All Processes, sorted with the heavy hitters to the top]

Comment: @Tetsujin I would love to collect that data but the freeze happens rather spontaneously. Any way to be constantly recording such data and then look back at it when the issue crops up?

Comment: Just leave Activity Monitor running & grab snaps after it happens. It won't show the stuck process directly, but it might give hints.